# "Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined" with Gatsby

Tags: reactjs, deployment, build, gatsby

I'm trying to host my Gatsby site on Firebase, but when I run the "gatbsy build" I get this error in my terminal:

```
 ERROR #98123  WEBPACK

Generating JavaScript bundles failed

Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined

not finished Generating image thumbnails
```

Here's my firebase.json file:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "ignore": ["firebase.json", "**/.*", "**/node_modules/**"],
    "headers": [
      {
        "source": "**/*",
        "headers": [
          {
            "key": "cache-control",
            "value": "public, max-age=0, must-revalidate"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "source": "static/**",
        "headers": [
          {
            "key": "cache-control",
            "value": "public, max-age=31536000, immutable"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "source": "**/*.@(css|js)",
        "headers": [
          {
            "key": "cache-control",
            "value": "public, max-age=31536000, immutable"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "source": "sw.js",
        "headers": [
          {
            "key": "cache-control",
            "value": "public, max-age=0, must-revalidate"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "source": "page-data/**",
        "headers": [
          {
            "key": "cache-control",
            "value": "public, max-age=0, must-revalidate"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

While my package-lock.json generates:

```
"array-includes": {
      "version": "3.1.3",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/array-includes/-/array-includes-3.1.3.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-gcem1KlBU7c9rB+Rq8/3PPKsK2kjqeEBa3bD5kkQo4nYlOHQCJqIJFqBXDEfwaRuYTT4E+FxA9xez7Gf/e3Q7A==",
      "requires": {
        "call-bind": "^1.0.2",
        "define-properties": "^1.1.3",
        "es-abstract": "^1.18.0-next.2",
        "get-intrinsic": "^1.1.1",
        "is-string": "^1.0.5"
      }
    },
```

And these are the other files where "includes" is declared:

```
return (
    <Wrapper ref={headerRef}>
      <Heading
        lineColor={lineColor}
        isActive={title.toLowerCase().includes(activeLink)}
      >
        {title}
      </Heading>
      <Paragraph>{paragraph}</Paragraph>
    </Wrapper>
  );

const doesConnectionSupportPrefetch = () => {
  if (`connection` in navigator && typeof navigator.connection !== `undefined`) {
    if ((navigator.connection.effectiveType || ``).includes(`2g`)) {
      return false;
    }

    if (navigator.connection.saveData) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  return true;
};
```

I've tried some possible solutions like updating Node, Babel and clearing up my cache. But no success yet. Any suggestion, please?

Comment: Hi there, the error just says something was supposed to be an array, but it's `undefined`. It's impossible to identify the issue without knowing what that something is / how it was used. Could you reproduce this error in a local build? Does it show you the error's location?

Comment: @DerekNguyen I can't build it. That's the returned error when I try to do it.
The first error during the process is "failed Building production JavaScript and CSS bundles". I'm pretty new to this. Pretty frustrated cause I can't even host my first website due to this error.

Comment: What does the error stack look like? i.e is there anything below the `not finished Generating image thumbnails` that indicates where the error occurs?

Comment: @DerekNguyen That is the last line in the error. Then it comes back to the normal prompt.

Comment: Hhmmm assuming it works properly during gatsby develop, search your code base for use of 'includes' with something that make use of browser api (window, document, etc). Without the actual code where the error happens, this can't be debugged

Comment: @DerekNguyen Yes, it does work normally on "gatsby develop". I've just included the other files left where "includes" is located, on my edit. Hope it helps and my question opens back. I just need to host a website, but it's getting SO complicated using Gatsby/JS.

Comment: Alright, my question about hosting a website is closed and apparently it will keep like that, without solving my issue. Thanks, Stack Overflow.